# On computing (a*b)%c when a,b,c are of the order of (x) e+18 in c

Tags: c, math, mathematical-optimization

I found these two codes to compute (a*b)%c when a, b, c is of the order of 10^18    , but could not get how they work can anyone explain me how these functions works line by line

```
long long int mult(long long int x, long long int y, long long int mod)
{
    x = x % mod;
    y = y % mod;
    long long int z = 0;
    for (1; x; x >>= 1){
            if(x & 1)
            if((z =z+ y) >= mod)
               z = z- mod;
            if((y = 2 * y) >= mod)
           y =y- mod;
     }
     return z;
}
```

and

```
long long multiple(long long a, long long b, long long c) // a * b % c
{
        if (b == 0) 
           return 0;

        long long ret = multiple(a, b >> 1, c);
        ret = (ret + ret) % c;
        if (b & 1) 
             ret = (ret + a) % c;
        return ret;
}
```

i have used these functions in solving online competitions and i have seen that the first function is way better/faster than the latter but why?

Comment: It seems that the biggest difference is that the second one uses recursion...?

Comment: That is clear that it uses recursion but it seems to do the same bit shift operation , first of all i need to understand how the bit shift helps here then why is first one much faster ... and FYI first one seems to work twice as fast the latter .

Comment: It's not only the recusion. Note how the second function uses the `%` operator on the intermediate results unconditionally. The first function handles this more efficiently by acknowledging that adding two numbers below `m` can only be greater than `m`, but not than `2*m`. The expensive modulo operation is replaced by a check and a subtraction.

Comment: can you please explain the use of bit-shifts used ?

Comment: @MOehm I would watch out about efficiency of `ifs` over arithmetics, if this was ran on a processor with fast arithmetic coprocessor/module and no branch prediction mechanism, modulos could turn out faster. It all depends how good is modulo implemented on cpu. But I don't have any data, or experience just hunch. Would appreciate any comment with real-world input.

Comment: @luk32: Performance of modulo versus comparison and subtraction may probably vary depending on machines. But in a quick test, just replacing the modulo parts with compare-and-subtract in the second routine brought the calculation time down to 60%. (But the first function is less than 30% of the original recursive function.)

Comment: @luk32: Another quick test, this time with more varied data. Checked loop (L) vs. recursion (R), modulo (M) vs. subtraction (S). Running times (LS: 0.976, RS: 1.236, LM: 4.996, RM: 6.427). LS and RM are OP's routines. Run on Intel64 with gcc. The modulo seems to have an impact. You can also bring down these times to (LS: 0.887, RS: 1.168, LM: 4.464, RM: 5.461) by using unsigned longs, for which the routine seems to be made anyway.

Comment: @MOehm Wow, great work. Also, to be clear, I didn't mean to suggest you weren't right, I suspected your findings for modern popular CPUs. I just wanted to note that it's good to know that this efficiency *might* not port to PowerPCs, BlueGene-kind or whatever CPUs they use nowadays in HPC centres. I really appreciate your input, after all currently I do most of computation on modern intel cpus, its worth to know it. Thanks again.

Comment: Side  question: why `for (1; x; x >>= 1){` instead of simply `for (; x; x >>= 1){`?

Comment: @chux i rewrote these functions and i have a habit of not leaving any argument blank so it can be just   for (; x; x >>= 1)

Comment: You should try using a debugger to step through the code line-by-line and see for yourself. Not trying to be insensitive, but that would probably answer most of your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bit-shifts are converting a multiplication operation into (conditional) addition.  Each time around the loop (1st method) or recursive call (2nd method) the code looks at the least-significant bit of one of the operands: if it is set, it adds the other operand to the running total.  It then shifts the first operand to the right (divides by two) and doubles the other operand (using modulus or subtraction if necessary).

For example, if the numbers were 5 and 7, 5 == 101 in binary so:

```
x      y      z
--     ---    ---
101    7      7   (bottom bit set, add 7 to z)
10     14         ( x = x >> 1 ; y = y * 2 )
10     14     7   (bottom bit not set, don't add)
1      28     7   ( x = x >> 1 ; y = y * 2 )
1      28     35  (bottom bit set, add 28 to z)
0                 ( x = x >> 1 ; x is zero so stop)
```